# Visual studio not changing to correct python version

Tags: python, visual-studio, interpreter

I am trying to change the python version on visual studio code from 2.7.10 to Python 3.8.1.

If I click on the python interpreter it says I am using Python 3.8

[image]

Then if I check the version in the terminal it also says

[image]

To change the Python interpreter first I changed the JSON settings file

```
    "python.pythonPath": "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8"
```

and then I ran these commands in the terminal because after this the terminal still was running on 2.7.10.

```html
echo $SHELL
echo $PATH
alias python=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8
```

Now both the terminal and visual studio seem to be running on 3.8 but I can't use the new f string format

```
print(f'hi {myVariable}')
```

but I can still use

```
print('hi {}'.format(myVariable))
```

I printed out the sys version, but the file is still using the old python, how do I change it to use the new one?

```
import sys; 
print(sys.version)
```

> output:
> 2.7.10 (default, Feb 22 2019, 21:55:15)     [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.37.14)]

Answer (score 0):

Try running your files using the `python3` command instead of `python`
so.. instead of

```
python test.py
```

you do

```
python3 test.py
```

(this is assuming that you manually run the python file from the terminal)